# LED light setup

Tags: led, resistors

I am trying to build a light to use on a video setup with 30 white LED's powered by 4 "c" batteries (6v). The connection would be parallel. Basically a 6V dc source with 30 white LED's and 30 resistors in parallel. The numbers I got are for a 150 ohms resistor, but I have gotten different values and I want to check if somebody can confirm my math.I am missing something ?

thanks in advance.
Ricardo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will give you around 20mA each. If you can keep them cool enough that should work. You will be wasting about half the energy in the resistors, so try to keep them away from the LEDs.

The calculation *can't* be exact- the battery voltage will change a lot during operation and the LED voltages are not well specified and they are different between different parts and at different temperatures (so the warmer ones at the center of the array will have a different brightness).

If you were to use a fancy chip such as an [ADD5211](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADD5211.pdf) you would get about double the operating time out of the batteries and a constant brightness during discharge, but it's more complex and probably more than you should attempt. I mention it for future readers. It's in a (somewhat miserable for prototyping) 4mm square package with 24 leads.

[image]

[image]

There are a lot (almost too many) similar backlight LED driver chips.

Comment: thanks a lot Spehro. I will take a look at this chip before I decide, just in case I could come up with something.

Comment: Would it be better to reduce the amount of resistors by connecting the LED in series, like 3, with one resistor per series ? I would have only 10 resistors on the circuit at that point.

Comment: You would need more like 12V to allow 3 white LEDs to be connected in series. It would be more efficient but the LEDs would dim more during the battery life. Trade-offs.